# Can't emulate flutter Code using Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, emulation

I have emulation problems in VSCode in my Flutter/Dart App, I sometimes get this error and can not get it to run properly. Sometimes it just works. Uninstalling Android Studio doesn't work, creating a new emulator doesn't work too.

This is the Error:

```
adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator
  Command: C:\Users\vit\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:35861
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

The few other posts about this topic don't work either. Does anyone have a clue how I can get my emulator to run *properly* ?